# What is the pronunciation of the 'a' in aqueous?

Tags: pronunciation

My teacher pronounces aqueous as "ay-kwee-ous", and as a result that's what my class has learnt.

However, I've become aware through several pronunciation guides (including Howjsay.com and a pronunciation video on YouTube) that "ah-kwee-ous" is seemingly a more common variant. The Yahoo dictionary lists both variants, with the "ah" version first. Dictionary.com also lists both, but the audio clip is of the "ay" version.

So what is most common/correct, and what should be used?

Comment: I suspect this depends on which side of the Atlantic you're sited on. BrE is /eɪ-/ not /ɑ:-/.

Comment: But we redress the balance when it comes to glaciers.

Comment: So /ɑ:-/ is more prevalent in American English? Personally, I'm located in Norway, but I strive toward attaining an American accent.

Comment: I don't know what Yahoo dictionary you're looking at. The [one I know about](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/aqueous) lists the "ay" first. Maybe you're confused by their pronunciation symbols.

Comment: @DarkLightA: If you want to ask more questions about English pronunciation in a silent medium like this, you'd do well to learn the [English phonemic alphabet](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf). Then, if you need to know the official pronunciation of any English word, you can look it up in the "English" part of any good _Spanish/French/German-English Bilingual Dictionary_. Because that's what everybody else in the world uses to represent English sounds, except for the USA and parts of the UK.

Comment: The various forms of phonemic symbols are foreign to me, so I'll comment as a layperson. I use "ah" for that sound, like an "ah-ha" moment. ah-kwee-us. That is how I hear most people say it. I am an American, from Indiana and living in Florida. (In case the geography makes a difference.)

Answer (score 2):

Oxford dictionaries has following mentions about pronunciation of *aqueous* :

- [British & World english](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aqueous): /ˈeɪkwɪəs/
- [American english](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/aqueous): /ˈākwēəs, ˈak-/

Comment: [American pronunciation:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aqueous) /ˈeɪkwiəs/ ***or*** /ˈækwiəs/. In my experience, /ˈeɪkwiəs/ is more common.

Comment: @peter,see the first [two results](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=aqueous%20oxford%20british&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=618148da8da2b836&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46226182,d.bmk&biw=1366&bih=659)

Comment: These two results say that the American pronunciation is  /ˈeɪkwiəs/ ***or*** /ˈækwiəs/ and that the British pronunciation is only /ˈeɪkwiəs/. Just what I said.

Comment: Don't expect other people to see the same Google search results that you do, especially not in the same order. The first two results for me are _aqueous_ (US) and _aqueous humor_ (no pronunciation given).

Comment: @Bradd, thanks. i thought that the link i provided pointed to specific result page but getting now that it represented the query string. However **1** [oxford/british & world english](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aqueous) ; **2** [oxford/american english](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/aqueous)

Comment: I think you're misreading the American phonetic notation (originated by Webster) that is used in the U.S. rather than IPA. The phonetic notation given is: /ˈākwēəs, ˈak-/. Translated to IPA, /ˈākwēəs/ is /ˈeɪkwiəs/, and  /ˈak-/ is /ˈæk-/

Answer (score -1):

Often the Oxford English Dictionary provides alternate regional pronunciations (such as American).  But in this case it has only /ˈeɪkwiːəs/ .